# How to filter all questions?

Tags: feature-request

I try to filter all questions to find out which question has the most votes.

[image]

At the moment you can only filter for active, hot, week and month. It would be really cool if there would be another button e.g. "alltime" or "all".

Comment: Have you clicked on the word "questions" in the banner?

Comment: Are you on mobile/using the app?

Comment: @HDE226868 I think the tag should be changed, but I'm not sure *what*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Questions -> Votes]

1. Click "Questions" in the banner.
2. Click "Votes" to sort the questions with the most voted questions on the top.